# why would a ? appear in IEnumerable<int>?.ToList()?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

I was reviewing some code and I came across the following line of code:

```
List authorIntList = authorIds?.ToList();
```

In the example above, authorIds is an IEnumerable. What is the purpose of the `?` in the line of code above?  I'm not sure I've ever seen this pattern before.  What does it do and in which version of .NET was it implemented?

Comment: [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

That's called [the "null conditional operator"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) -- i.e. `?` and `.` together -- new to C# 6.0.  What it means is that, if `authorIds` is *not* `null`, then it will call/return `ToList()` on it.  Otherwise, it will return null.  It's basically syntactic sugar so you don't have to write lengthier code like `List AuthorIntList = authorIds != null ? authorIds.ToList() : null;`.

Answer (score 0):

The "Null Conditional Operator" exists as a way to shorthand "If this isn't null, do the thing, otherwise return null".  It's basically the same as

```
List authorIntList = authorIds ? authorIDs.ToList() : null; //null coalescing
```

or

```
List authorIntList = null;
if(authorIDs != null) { authorIntList = authorIDs.ToList(); } //traditional if
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a null conditional operator that in many languages people call it Elvis operator. It has been added from c# 6.0 and checks your code with null.

So if you have something like:

```
var x= a?.b?.c?.d;
```

x will be null if any of a,b,c or d be null. and it will be the value in d if all of them are not null. before you had to put them in if conditions.

```
if(a!= null && a.b!= null && a.b.c!= null)
{
    x= a?.b?.c?.d;
}
```

Comment: Not Elvis. See comments under Woot's answer.

Comment: @rory.ap I've already wrote that it is called null conditional . in the c# 6.0 introduction in mva.microsoft.com they've mentioned the name Elvis for it but they wasn't sure that they are going to use that name.

Answer (score -1):

Correction Null Conditional operator
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

It's like saying if authorId's is not null then execute ToList() else returns null.

Comment: It's actually not quite the same.

Comment: Elvis is the null coalescing `?:`, not the null conditional `?.`.

Comment: @rory.ap: the null coalescing operator `??` isn't quite the same either because it compares to null rather than false.

Comment: True.  C# doesn't actually have a true `Elvis` operator.